# Close browser tab after executing a post

Tags: python, html, wsgi

I have a wsgi python-2 web server and I would like that after pressing a button, executing some code on server side, the browser page would close.

At the moment the post redirects the browser tab to a hostname/foo page and I would like to not do that but just receive the post and close the page on client side.

This page is a legacy one and the less code is touched the better (it has already been reworked from scratch but I have to keep it as simple as possible for compatibility issues).

So for example the execution flow would be like this:

```
user clicks on "foo" button -> a post arrives to the web server -> the server does something on its side 
-> page closes
```

From what I know an html page can be closed with a `window.close();` command but I have no idea how to insert this command in the current page.

I have tried creating a javascript function bounded to the onclick and onsubmit listeners but I was not able to solve the issue as the /foo page is always printed.

The existing code is like that:

```
<form method="post" action="foo">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit and foo!"/>
</form>
```

The foo function calls a foo function in python-webserver as per wsgi programming model.

What I would like to do is to automatically close the page after pressing the Submit and Foo form submission button

Comment: So you want to send request and then immediately close browser or send request, wait for answer then close browser?

Comment: It makes no difference in this case, as the client sends a POST with some data that triggers code execution on server side whose results stay in the server side (the client can close as soon the POST is correctly sent)

Comment: Note that the `<input>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using JavaScript [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) object combined with [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send) and thus do on submit event

```
var formElement = document.querySelector("form");
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("POST", "foo", true);
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.HEADERS_RECEIVED) {
        window.close();
    }
}
request.send(new FormData(formElement));
```

Note that this assume you have single form on your page. If you prefer to close at another moment, replace `HEADERS_RECEIVED` with one of other [readyState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState) value. Disclaimer: this code was not tested.

Comment: Code seems not to be working, as "foo" seems not to be equivalent to "action". The server  receives a hostname/foo in the "action" case but just "hostname" in the "javascript" (aka this code) case

Comment: @EagleOne this repalcing `"foo"` using `document.querySelector("form").action`

Comment: Thank you @Daweo, this solves the "action" issue, but the request.onreadystatechange = function() branch is never taken (added some alerts here and there). I have assigned an ID to the form and added a getElementById call instead of querySelector